# How do I pause a function in c or objective-c on mac without using sleep()

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Hi I would like to pause the execution of a function in an cocoa project.  I dont want to use sleep() because the function needs to resume after user interaction.  I also want to avoid doing this with multiple calls to sleep.

Thanks for your responses.  Ok I started the code while waiting for some answers.  I then realized that sleep or pause would not be usefull to me because it freeses my whole program.  I think I might have to do some threading.  Here is the situation:

I have a program that uses coreplot.  I also use it to debug and develop algorithms so I do lots of plots while the data is being processed (ie in the midfle of the code but I need the flexibility to put it anywhaere so I cant separate my function). I was able to do this with NSRunAlertPanel but having a message box like that doesnt make it very presentable and I cant do much with the main window while an alert is open.

I hope I am not too confusing with my explanation but if I am ill try to one line it here:

I would like to interact with my cocoa interface while one of my functions is stopped in the middle of what it is doing.

Comment: I think there is too little information here for a good answer.  Do you want to wait for user input? Or are you waiting for some other condition? Should your program continue doing other things in the mean time? Please be more specific.

Comment: So, you want to wait for a given time period or until the next event arrives?

Comment: Yes my program needs to keep working in the mean time.  Right now I have a cocoa interface, when I press a button the IBAction method calls another method which needs to be put to put on hold a couple of times during its execution.

Answer (score 3):

Its sounds to me like you're looking for -NSRunLoop runUntilDate:

Apple's Docs: [runUntilDate](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsrunloop_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000321-BABCHDGI)

This code will cause the execution within your method to pause but still let other events like timers and user input occur:

```
while ( functionShouldPause )
{
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
}
```

Switching functionShouldPause back to false will allow the rest of the method to execute.

Answer (score 2):

It seems more like you are interested in reacting to user events rather than "pausing" the function.  You would probably want to put the code that you want to execute into another function that is called as a result of the user's actions.

Comment: I need to react to user events but my function must stop what it is doing until user event.  I cant breakdown my function I need to put those anywhere I want

Answer (score 1):

In C you can use the [`pause()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pause) function in `<unistd.h>`. This causes the calling program to suspend until it receives a signal, at which point the `pause` call will return and your program will continue (or call a signal handler; depending on what signal was received).

Comment: That won't really help with the “resume after user interaction” part.

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like you want to break the function into two parts; the bit that happens before the sleep and the bit that happens afterward. Before going to sleep, register for a notification that calls the "after" code, and can be triggered by the UI (by an `IBAction` connected to whatever UI element). Now instead of calling `sleep()`, run the run loop for the period you want to go to sleep for, then after that has returned post the "after" notification. In the "after" code, remove the object as an observer for that notification. Now, whichever happens first - the time runs out or the user interrupts you - you get to run the "after" code.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a clock or timer function? When your button is pressed start running a loop like timeTillAction = 10 and do a loop of timeTillAction = timeTillAction - 1 until it reaches 0 then run whatever code after the 10 seconds.

Sorry if this isn't well explained.